# XML PARSER -Parsing a large file for a particular format output

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, large-files, seek

I am trying to parse a *large xml* file and print the tags to an output file. I am using *minidom*, my code is working fine for 30Mb files but for larger ones it is getting memory error. So I used bufferred reading the on file but now I am unable to get the desired output.

### XML File

```
> <File> <TV>Sony</TV> <FOOD>Burger</FOOD> <PHONE>Apple</PHONE> </File>   
> <File> <TV>Samsung</TV> <FOOD>Pizza</FOOD> <PHONE>HTC</PHONE> </File>  
> <File> <TV>Bravia</TV> <FOOD>Pasta</FOOD> <PHONE>BlackBerry</PHONE> </File>
```

### Desired Output

Sony, Burger, Apple
Samsung, Pizza, HTC
Bravia, Pasta, BlackBerry

When reading with buffer its giving me an output saying :-
Sony, Burger, Apple
*Samsung,Piz*
Bravia, Pasta, BlackBerry

```
while 1:
    content = File.read(2048)
        if not len(content):
            break
         else:
             for lines in StringIO(content):
                lines = lines.lstrip(' ')
                if lines.startswith("<TV>"):
                   TV =  lines.strip("<TV>")
                   tvVal = TV.split("</TV>")[0]
                   #print tvVal
                   w2.writelines(str(tvVal)+",")
                elif lines.startswith("<FOOD>"):
                   FOOD =  lines.strip("<FOOD>")
                   foodVal = FOOD.split("</FOOD>")[0]
                   #print foodVal
                   w2.writelines(str(foodVal)+",")
                   ............................
                   ...........................
```

I tried with **seek()** but still I was unable to get the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your support and i have finally written my code and its working great here it is

```
import lxml import etree    
for event, element in etree.iterparse(the_xml_file):
    if 'TV' in element.tag:
        print element.text
```

Answer (score 1):

You're reading in 2048 byte at once, which put the reading cursor in the middle of a line. In the next read, the rest of that line is discard because it doesn't start with a tag.

Instead of rolling your own parser, consider using [`iterparse`](http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm#incremental-parsing). An even faster version of `iterparse` is included with [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/parsing.html)
Here's an example

```
import cStringIO
from xml.etree.ElementTree import iterparse

fakefile = cStringIO.StringIO("""<temp>
  <email id="1" Body="abc"/>
  <email id="2" Body="fre"/>
  <email id="998349883487454359203" Body="hi"/>
</temp>
""")
for _, elem in iterparse(fakefile):
    if elem.tag == 'email':
        print elem.attrib['id'], elem.attrib['Body']
    elem.clear()
```

Comment: As i have already said that i used _minidom_ parser and it worked superb but only problem i am having is in **large size files** and reading it in buffer. I should be checking with <File> </File> tags if the buffer gives me the last line somewhere <FOOD> Pasta; i should rollback and search for </File>.Proceeding with seek() & tell() but all i am confused and landed up here for help.

Comment: `Iterparse` is designed to work with huge files, because you can use it to parse the file iteratively, discard unnecessary information. You don't have to keep the entire file into memory, unlike `minidom`

Comment: `import cStringIO    
    from xml.etree.ElementTree import iterparse    
    File = open("File.xml","rb")    
    FRead = File.read()    
    x = cStringIO.StringIO(Fread)    
    for event, elem in iteparse(x):    
        if elem.tag == 'File':    
             print elem.attrib['TV']    
         elem.clear()`  
  
    This isnt working :(

Comment: In your example `TV` is a child element, not an attribute. And don't read the whole file into a `StringIO`, it will defeats the purpose of `iterparse`. Just pass the file to `iterparse` directly.